# Como ler o retorno do webservice json (WEBSERVICE - JSON)

Tags: java, android, json, array

Tenho esse *JSON*:

```
 {
  "articleList": {
    "conversas": [
      {
        "cd_resultadofinanceiro": "24",
        "cd_feedbackfinanceiro": "61",
        "mm_resultado": "Tomar as devida providencia judiciais.",
        "dt_resultado": "2015-04-01 10:59:00",
        "cd_pessoa_editor": "334",
        "cd_financeiroparcela": "119",
        "cd_pessoa": "334",
        "no_pessoa": "Aurora Souza",
        "ts_modificacao": "2015-03-27 17:11:15.296784",
        "bo_pessoafisica": "t",
        "ds_resultadofinanceiro": "Enviar para departamento juridico",
        "cd_statusfinanceiro": "5"
      },
      {
        "cd_resultadofinanceiro": "18",
        "cd_feedbackfinanceiro": "50",
        "mm_resultado": "N\u00e3o efetuou o pagamento na data.",
        "dt_resultado": "2015-04-01 10:42:00",
        "cd_pessoa_editor": "333",
        "cd_financeiroparcela": "119",
        "cd_pessoa": "333",
        "no_pessoa": "Marcia Candida",
        "ts_modificacao": "2015-03-27 17:07:13.593143",
        "bo_pessoafisica": "t",
        "ds_resultadofinanceiro": "Fazer contato com o cliente",
        "cd_statusfinanceiro": "7"
      },
      {
        "cd_resultadofinanceiro": "21",
        "cd_feedbackfinanceiro": "47",
        "mm_resultado": "Divida a vencer",
        "dt_resultado": "2015-03-30 11:26:00",
        "cd_pessoa_editor": "333",
        "cd_financeiroparcela": "119",
        "cd_pessoa": "333",
        "no_pessoa": "Marcia Candida",
        "ts_modificacao": "2015-03-27 17:07:13.593143",
        "bo_pessoafisica": "t",
        "ds_resultadofinanceiro": "Divida a vencer",
        "cd_statusfinanceiro": "6"
      }
    ],
    "produtor": [
      {
        "cd_telefone": "577",
        "cd_pessoa": "329",
        "cd_documento": "690",
        "no_pessoa": "Carlos Henrique Silva",
        "ts_modificacao": "2015-03-31 09:19:00",
        "bo_pessoafisica": "t",
        "mm_documento": "28979967497",
        "cd_orgaoexpedidor": "1",
        "cd_tipodocumento": "2",
        "nr_telefone": "6497885656",
        "cd_tipotelefone": "6"
      }
    ]
  }
}

    {
      "articleList": {
        "conversas": [
          {
            "cd_resultadofinanceiro": "24",
            "cd_feedbackfinanceiro": "61",
            "mm_resultado": "Tomar as devida providencia judiciais.",
            "dt_resultado": "2015-04-01 10:59:00",
            "cd_pessoa_editor": "334",
            "cd_financeiroparcela": "119",
            "cd_pessoa": "334",
            "no_pessoa": "Aurora Souza",
            "ts_modificacao": "2015-03-27 17:11:15.296784",
            "bo_pessoafisica": "t",
            "ds_resultadofinanceiro": "Enviar para departamento juridico",
            "cd_statusfinanceiro": "5"
          },
          {
            "cd_resultadofinanceiro": "18",
            "cd_feedbackfinanceiro": "50",
            "mm_resultado": "N\u00e3o efetuou o pagamento na data.",
            "dt_resultado": "2015-04-01 10:42:00",
            "cd_pessoa_editor": "333",
            "cd_financeiroparcela": "119",
            "cd_pessoa": "333",
            "no_pessoa": "Marcia Candida",
            "ts_modificacao": "2015-03-27 17:07:13.593143",
            "bo_pessoafisica": "t",
            "ds_resultadofinanceiro": "Fazer contato com o cliente",
            "cd_statusfinanceiro": "7"
          },
          {
            "cd_resultadofinanceiro": "21",
            "cd_feedbackfinanceiro": "47",
            "mm_resultado": "Divida a vencer",
            "dt_resultado": "2015-03-30 11:26:00",
            "cd_pessoa_editor": "333",
            "cd_financeiroparcela": "119",
            "cd_pessoa": "333",
            "no_pessoa": "Marcia Candida",
            "ts_modificacao": "2015-03-27 17:07:13.593143",
            "bo_pessoafisica": "t",
            "ds_resultadofinanceiro": "Divida a vencer",
            "cd_statusfinanceiro": "6"
          }
        ],
        "produtor": [
          {
            "cd_telefone": "577",
            "cd_pessoa": "329",
            "cd_documento": "690",
            "no_pessoa": "Carlos Henrique Silva",
            "ts_modificacao": "2015-03-31 09:19:00",
            "bo_pessoafisica": "t",
            "cd_orgaoexpedidor": "1",
            "cd_tipodocumento": "2",
            "nr_telefone": "6497885656",
            "cd_tipotelefone": "6"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Tento pegar assim:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray retorno = json.getJSONArray("conversas");

            int tamanho = json.getJSONArray("conversas").length();
            //Log.i("conversa",""+tamanho);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + " "+tamanho , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            int cont = 0;
            int i = 0;

            for (i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
                FinanceiroConversaClass financeiroconversas = new FinanceiroConversaClass();
                financeiroconversas.setDivida("" + retorno.getJSONObject(cont).getString("mm_resultado"));
                financeiroconversas.setNome("" + retorno.getJSONObject(cont).getString("no_pessoa"));
                financeiroconversas.setData("" + retorno.getJSONObject(cont).getString("dt_resultado"));
                financeiroconversas.setMsg("" + retorno.getJSONObject(cont).getString("mm_resultado"));

                financeirosconversas.add(financeiroconversas);
                cont++;
            }
```

Mas não está dando certo.

segue logcat:
07-17 12:55:59.400    8490-8490/com.ipeweb.toobar W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: No value for conversas

Comment: O que ocorre? Exibe algum erro? Tente especificar melhor o que não deu certo!

Comment: Será que tenho que percorrer com 2 laços ?

Comment: conversas está dentro de articleList , certo? então antes de pegar a conversa terá pe navegar até articleList !

Comment: ThiagoLuizDomacoski você está correto, mas como faço já tentei e nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apenas  diminui o JSON para testar:

```
String s = "{ \"articleList\": { \"conversas\": [ { \"cd_resultadofinanceiro\": \"24\" },  {\"cd_resultadofinanceiro\": \"18\"}]}}";

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);

        JSONObject articleList = jsonObject.getJSONObject("articleList"); 
        JSONArray conversas =articleList.getJSONArray("conversas");
        JSONObject cd_resultadofinanceiro =conversas.getJSONObject(0);
        System.out.println(cd_resultadofinanceiro.get("cd_resultadofinanceiro"));



    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Olá amigo Thiago L. Muito obrigado deu certo d+ abraço